# How to stop real-to-varchar(50) conversion in SQL Server from truncating values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several `real` values in a table.

```
42.1234323
38.0234042
40.1112311
```

However, even if I specify `varchar(50)` like this:

```
cast(<<value>> as varchar(50))
```

they drop characters:

```
42.12
38.023
40.111
```

How do I stop that? I need all of the numbers...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str()` for the conversion:

```
select str(col, 10, 7)
```

It is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx).

An alternative method converts to `decimal` first:

```
select convert(varchar(255), convert(decimal(10, 7), col))
```

Comment: Never know the existence of `str`

Comment: @Prdp . . . It is SQL Server-specific.